# Let $E/L$ be an elliptic curve. Why is Galois cohomology $H^1(G,E(L))$ finite group?

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, elliptic-curves, galois-cohomology

Let $L$ be a finite extension of number field $K$.
Let $G=Gal(L/K)$. Let $E/L$ be an elliptic curve defined over $L$. Let $E(L)$ be
$L $ rational point of $E$.

Then, why is Galois cohomology $H^1(G,E(L))$ finite group ?

If $E/L$ has rank $0$, both $G$ and $E(L)$ is finite, so the claim is obvious.
But in the case $rank(E/L)≧1$, $E(L)$ is infinite set so I think there is no reason $H^1(G,E(L))$ to be finite.

Comment: If $M$ is finitely generated $G$-module, then $H^p(G,M)$ is finitely generated abelian group (from standard resolution); if $G$ is moreover finite, then $H^p(G,M)$ is torsion (from restriction-corestriction) so it must be finite. Apply this to $M = E(L)$, this is finitely generated by Mordell-Weil

Comment: Then you, latter is that $H^2(G,M)$ is killed by order of $G$ by restriction・lcorestriction argument, could you tell me a reason of the former (When $M$ is f.g then $H^p(G,M)$ is f.g) reason?

Comment: this follows when one computes $H^p(G,M)$ via a free $G$-resolution of $\mathbb{Z}$, then take $\text{Hom}( , M)$.

Comment: Is it difficult to prove that elementary ? Specifically, if $M$ is generated by $a_1,・・・,a_n$, maps from $G$ to $M$ is generated by $n\sharp G$ elements..